# What does the confusion_matrix line of code do?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
model = Pipeline([('vectorizer',tvec),('classifier',clf2)])
model.fit(IV_train, DV_train)
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
predictions = model.predict(IV_test)
confusion_matrix(predictions, DV_test)
```

I want to know what the confusion matrix line in the code does.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of the function? 

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html

Is there a specific line in the documentation that you struggle with?

Comment: in my case is y_true DV_test and y_pred predictions?

Comment: A confusion matrix contains the accuracy of your model, comparing the prediction with the ground truth.

Answer (score 0):

A confusion matrix is a tabular summary of the number of correct and incorrect predictions made by a classifier.
https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-create-a-confusion-matrix-in-python-using-scikit-learn